# Probability of Modulus of a sum of two symmetric random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, symmetric and identically distributed random variables. Let  $$P\left(\left|X+Y\right|\le K\right)>A$$ for $K, A$ constants. Show that there exist constants $(K_1,K_2,A_1,A_2)$ so that

1. $P\left(\left|X\right|\le K_1\right)>A_1$ and
2. $P\left(\left|Y\right|\le K_2\right)>A_2$.\

Is this solution as following right

$P\left(  |X+Y|\le K\right)> A$

$ \Rightarrow P\left(  X+Y\le K\right)> A/2$ becouse of the symmetry of X+Y

$ \Rightarrow P\left(  X\le K,Y\le 0\right)> A/2$

$ \Rightarrow P\left(  X\le K \right) P\left( Y\le 0\right)> A/2$

$ \Rightarrow P\left(  X\le K \right) . 1/2 > A/2$
$

$\Rightarrow P(X\le K)>A$

$\Rightarrow P(|X|\le K)>2A$

and the same for Y we can see that

$\Rightarrow P(|Y|\le K)>2A$

Comment: There is some important information missing in your question. For instance, I can always get $P(|X|\leq K_1)>1/2$ by taking $K_1$ large enough. The fact that $X,Y$ are i.i.d and symmetric is not needed for this.